# Correlation: make a graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have dataframe and I try to print graph.
I use

```
df = pd.read_excel('resp1.xlsx')
corr = df.corr()
sns.set(context="paper", font="monospace")

df = sns.load_dataset("brain_networks", header=[0, 1, 2], index_col=0)

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 9))

sns.heatmap(corr, vmax=.8, square=True)

networks = corr.columns.get_level_values("network")
for i, network in enumerate(networks):
    if i and network != networks[i - 1]:
        ax.axhline(len(networks) - i, c="w")
        ax.axvline(i, c="w")
f.tight_layout()
```

but it return `ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 �� �������� ����������� Win32.` in pycharm and `KeyError: 'Level network must be same as name (None)'` in Spyder(anaconda).
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think those %1 errors are related to mixing 64 bit and 32 bit of app/dll. You also have the `win32` hint. Perhaps you use a 64 bit python with 32 bit package (pandas or other) or the opposite.

Comment: Is any way to build that?

Comment: If you use a 64bit python, you should install the 64bit packages as well.